# Webview Keyboard Issue

Tags: android, flutter, webview, flutter-layout

Webview Keyboard not working after resume. The Keyboard is visible but text entered is not reflecting in the view.

```
InAppWebView(initialUrl: url,
gestureRecognizers: <Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>[
new Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(
() => new EagerGestureRecognizer(),
),
].toSet(),
initialHeaders: {},
initialOptions: InAppWebViewWidgetOptions(
crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
debuggingEnabled: false,
javaScriptEnabled: true,
clearCache: false,
)),
onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
webView = controller;
})
```